# Looping through image object using ACF and CPT UI [SOLVED]

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, images, advanced-custom-fields

### Answer

https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/7h7e9r/looping_through_image_object_using_acf_and_cpt_ui/

[Rishadan](https://www.reddit.com/user/Rishadan) on reddit gave a simple answer to this question. I'm finding the **WHY** out at the moment but the answer is the `$website_image = get_field('website_image')` variable needs to be defined in the `while` loop. Then you can access the arrays different properties like so `echo $website_image['url']`. If you want to create the variable outside of the loop, you would need to provide a `post_id` parameter.

### Problem

Cannot access values of array in an **Image Object** from **Advanced Custom Fields**

### Expected Result

Should be able to access **URL** and **ALT** specifically, but would like to know how to access the rest

### MAIN

I have a section on a site I'm working on where I want to be able to create an indefinite amount of content for that area. So I bring in Advanced Custom Fields and create a Custom Post Type, write my loop, and now I'm stuck.

I'm not very familiar with PHP to be completely honest, I'm kind of learning as I go. So I understand that with images, ACF can return an `image object` and you can easily access any of the keys using bracket notation ie.

```
<?php    
$website_image = get_field('website_image');
?>

<img src="<?php echo $website_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php $website_image['alt']; ?>">
```

This is just an extremely simple example, but if you uploaded and image to a custom field with a type of image, you could display the image like this. It seems that when returning an `Image Object` from ACF and using it in a Custom Post Type, this method does not work

```
<?php    
  // Notice the use of the_field() instead of get_field()
  $website_image = the_field('website_image');
?>

<img src="<?php echo $website_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php $website_image['alt']; ?>">
```

I realize that I can just simply use the image as a **Featured Image** and be done with this, but I would really like to figure this out in case I were to ever need to add multiple images to a single post type.

### ACF > Portfolio Site Images

```
Field Label: Website Image
Field Name: website_image
Field Type: Image
Return Value: Image Object
```

### Custom Post Type > Portfolio Sites

```
Post Type Slug: portfolio_sites
Plural Label: Portfolio Sites
Singular Label: Portfolio Site
```

### content-portfolio.php

```
<?php

  $portfolio_header = get_field('portfolio_header');
  $website_image = the_field('website_image');

?>

<a name="portfolio"></a>
<section id="home-portfolio-section" class="container-fluid">
  <header class="row mb-5 pt-5">
    <h2 class="h1">
      <?php echo $portfolio_header; ?>
    </h2>
  </header> <!-- row -->

  <article class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">

        <?php
          $loop = new WP_QUERY(
            [
              'post_type' => 'portfolio_sites',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'orderby' => 'ID'
            ]
          );

          if ($loop->have_posts()) :
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
              <div class="col-12 mb-5 col-md-6">
                // This next line is the problem
                <img src="<?php the_field('website_image'); ?>" alt="">
              </div>    
        <?php
          endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
        ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

### Failed Attempts

`echo the_field('website_image')` returns a list of the arrays values

```
46,
,
testservert-xs,
,
,
image/png,
http://localhost/wptest/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/testservert-xs.png,
575,
264,
Array
```

If I attempt a `var_dump($website_image)` where `$website_image = the_field('website_image')` it returns `NULL`

A `var_dump($website_image)` where `$website_image = get_field('website_image')` returns `bool(false)`

Comment: You're using `the_field()` wrong in several places. You have a comment that says `// Notice the use of the_field() instead of get_field()`. Why? `the_field()` echos the value and `get_field()` returns it. If you're assigning to a variable you need to _return_ it.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd like to point out that if I assign `$website_image = get_field('website_image')` it will either return `echo $website_image['url'];` it returns empty, not even a `NULL`. If I try `<img src="<?php echo $website_image['url'] ?>">` and inspect it in devtools, it returns `<img src(unknown)>` and a `var_dump($website_image)` returns a `bool(false)`

Comment: You either don't have an image selected on that field or have the name of the field incorrect.

Comment: Well if you look under `Failed Attempts` at the bottom of the question, I use `the_field('website_image')` and it returns an array, with values. So there is definitely an image, and if it returns an array how is the name incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

`the_field()` directly echoes the contents of a field. If you want to use `the_field()` , you should change the field output to url in acf settings panel (Where you created the field).

If you however wish to play around with `var_dump()` and return a specific value from an object, you should use `get_field('field_name')`.

So in your example, that would look something like this:

```
<?php
    if(get_field('website_image')):
    $wimg = get_field('website_image');?>
    <img src="<?php echo $wimg['url']; ?>">
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, you're probably on to something here but that wouldn't work because I need to loop through every post in the `portfolio_sites` post type. This question has actually been answered here https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/7h7e9r/looping_through_image_object_using_acf_and_cpt_ui/

Comment: That also works, but as I've said, you'd need to set it as "url output". Alternatively you could just go with  get_field('website_image', $post->ID); then just do the same $wimg['url'];